# Efficient way to find if it is possible to create a word from a list by using words from another list

Tags: python, list, set, logic

I have two lists one is ***expected_entities*** and other is ***extracted_words***. The list expected_entities is comprised of strings which can each contain multiple words or a single word. While the list extracted_words contains strings with single words. I need to find out if any expected_entity from expected_entities can be constructed using multiple or single entries from extracted_words.

For example,

`expected_entities = {"hello joe", "hi julie", "hola sam", "paul"}`
`extracted_words = {"hello", "hi", "hola", "sam"}`

My code should return `hola sam` as the output.

Currently, my solution looks like this:

```
def my_method(expected_entities, extracted_words):
    for expected_entity in expected_entities:
        words = expected_entity.split()
        if set(words) < set(extracted_words):
            return expected_entity
```

I wanted to know if there can be a better solution to achieve the same this doesn't seem to work fine.

*Note - Please assume that the data will be such that only one expected_entity could be created from extracted_words.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very efficient for now, but this will get the job done.

```
expected_entities = {"hello joe", "hi julie", "hola sam", "paul"}
extracted_words = {"hello", "hi", "hola", "sam"}

def my_method(expected_entities, extracted_words):
    for expected_entity in expected_entities:
        words = expected_entity.split()
        if all(word in extracted_words for word in words):
            return expected_entity

my_method(expected_entities, extracted_words)

# 'hola sam'
```

Comment: Thanks this works, I am not very active here on StackOverflow can you also tell me what could be the reason for a downvote on the question, I mean I tried to be as descriptive as possible. :confused:

Comment: Your question might be close to being a duplicate, that's probably the reason for these kind of down votes. Still the down voter should have explained why he did down vote indeed. @ManthanJamdagni

Comment: Actually, this does not work if you add one more correct entry to `expected_entities`- for example: `"hi sam"`. In this case it outputs `hi sam` only and not both `hi sam` and `hola sam`.

Comment: @BcK they are not dictionaries. That are sets - a different data structure.

Comment: @theausome mistyped my mistake.

Comment: @BcK oops! Didn't see the *Note* part. Forget everything. :)

Comment: @theausome no problem :)